# How to sync Facebook calendar in my Android phone calendar?

Tags: calendar, facebook

Is there a way to sync my Facebook calendar with the inbuilt Phone calendar of Android. I know there are many apps, but I do not want to give them permission to access my profile details.

Comment: *This is how you do it:*
https://www.facebook.com/help/152652248136178 *And then in Google do this:*
https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37100?hl=en

Answer (score 4):

Of course Facebook likes so much to break compatibility with whatever it ever developed... so now the method is different:

- On Web Facebook, choose the event you want to have in the Calendar
- Set the participation (Going/Maybe)
- Click the 3-dots menu and choose "Export Event"
- Ensure that the "Save in calendar" option is selected
- **The link shown below that choice is what you need in your Calendar app** (e.g. https://www.facebook.com/events/ical/upcoming/?uid=MYUSERID&key=MYACCESSKEY). Right-click & copy the link.
- On Google calendar click the `+` button to add a calendar, and select *"From URL"*.
- Paste the URL and choose "Add calendar"
- Profit

If it doesn't work immediately ensure that the calendar is syncing and wait a little more.

## ---- [OLD METHOD] -----

## Obtain calendar URL from [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/)

- Go to [Facebook Events](https://www.facebook.com/events/) via a Desktop browser (or set the Mobile browser identification to *as Desktop*)
- Scroll to *Upcoming Events* link, at the bottom of the right column
- Right-click on the link and *Copy address*

## Add the calendar from its URL

- Go to [Google Calendar](https://calendar.google.com)
- Click *Menu* to show it
- Click on the icon on the side of *Add Calendar* and choose *From URL*
- Paste the URL obtained before and *Make calendar public*; if you are ok with that. It is necessary to show it on Android.

## Sync the calendar, on Android

- Open the Google Calendar app
- Tap on *Menu* and then *Settings*
- Scroll to find the calendar *Events on Facebook* and tap on it. If is not shown yet, come back to the calendar, tap on the three-dots icon and choose *Refresh*
- Enable *Sync*

Et Voilà! Enjoy your Facebook events directly on Android and any device you desire, without having to open Facebook website or app

**Note:** the calendar is read-only. So, unfortunately, for now is not possible to set custom notifications for the events (that actually would be make this setup perfect, given the pretty short time ahead that Facebook uses for its reminders).

**PS:** my Google Calendar web app was not set in english, so items could be named slightly different.

Comment: This does not work,  there is no Events on Facebook in calendar

Comment: Facebook changed it one about 1 month ago. Everybody already subscribed should have got a notification of this change. The new method more cumbersome; take a look at: https://tendee.io/guide/how-to-add-facebook-events-to-calendar/ . I'll try to update my answer.

Comment: I updated the answer; now it should be the correct procedure.

Comment: I HAVE my Facebook calendar in Google calendar on the web, in the section "Other calendars". Freshly imported, working, syncing. But only the main calendar is invisible on Android when I choose calendars to display.

Comment: Did you remember to set the calendar **as "public"** so it can be shared and be seen from different apps?

Comment: You are right. The calendar was not public. And I have found one good trick: make calendar public in Google calendar, enable sync on Android. Then you can delete a public Google Facebook calendar and add the same calendar as non-public.Sync will still work!

Comment: Neat trick, thanks for reporting it! And glad you manage to make it work!

Answer (score 1):

Facebook doesn't allow it - you would have to use another app like Haxsync and give it permission to access your profile.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Facebook, using a laptop or PC, go to https://www.facebook.com/events/calendar
2. In the top right corner there is a "Add to Calendar" button, *RIGHT CLICK* this, and choose "copy link address".

- This link will look like https://www.facebook.com/events/ical/upcoming/?uid=&key=

3. In Google Calendar, using a laptop or PC, on the left side look for "Other calendars", click the + icon next to that, choose "Subscribe to calendar".
4. Choose "From URL", paste your Facebook calendar link, click "Add calendar". Voila!

On your Android phone the Facebook Calendar events will be synced.

If you do not use a Google Account on your Android phone, then this procedure will not work for you.